# Use of masonry with infinite scroll content creates unstyled flash

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

We are using `masonry` in conjunction with infinite scroll (by Paul Irish).

Our markup is similar to this:

```
<div id="Container">
    <div class="project">...</div>
    <div class="project">...</div>
    <div class="project">...</div>
    <div class="project">...</div>
    <div class="project">...</div>
    <div class="project">...</div>

    <div class="pagination">...</div>
</div>
```

the `div.project` elements are the ones that are the 'bricks' being used by Masonry. The pagination essentially appends the content after the last div.project element.

However, we are having two problems:

1. When the page loads, there is an unstyled flash of content. The initial content loads in place, and then suddenly, it all shrinks to the size of ONE block, with all the pages content, then animates out to their respective positions.
2. When appending the content via infinitescroll, it will have similar behavior, except it doesnt appear in place first. It all loads in one box to the top left of the vacant area (below the previous content) and animates outwards right and down.

We want to somewhat replicate this behavior:

- http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html
- http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html

I am having a heck of a time trying to get the stuff to animate correctly, and position correctly on the page. I have managed to circumvent the overlap issue I was having by assigning explicit widths to the images in the blocks [I could have used $.imagesLoaded() - but I want to lessen our footprint.

Questions:

1. Do we need to do any preparation on the existing content? (ie: CSS styles, js listeners, etc)
2. Do I need to define the CSS animations or jQuery animations explicitly? I cannot seem to find the definition of the animations in the examples listed above.

Thank you.

Resources:

[Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

[Infinite Scroll (Paul Irish)](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)